# Days since last session - for users with session level custom dimension - BigQuery - Google Analytics

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've got the following SQL query, which I got from the Lunametrics blog. Works fine. However, what I want to be able to do is have an additional column showing the value of a session level custom variable.

What I have right now is:

```
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitId,
  DATEDIFF(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime), 
SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(prevVisitStartTime)) AS daysSinceLastSession,
 FLOOR((visitStartTime - prevVisitStartTime)/60) as minutesSinceLastSession
FROM (
 SELECT
fullvisitorid,
visitId,
visitStartTime,
LAG(visitStartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorid ORDER BY visitStartTime 
ASC) AS prevVisitStartTime
FROM
TABLE_DATE_RANGE([DATA],
TIMESTAMP ('2017-04-01'),
TIMESTAMP ('2017-04-08')))
```

I've been trying to introduce a column for a custom dimension with index 30, but without success. Basically, I just want to be able to see the days since last session for visitors which contained this custom dimension. My code for this is:

```
max(case when hits.customdimensions.index = 30 then hits.customdimensions.value end) customerId
```

EDIT: this shows how I thought I could introduce this custom dimension as a new column, but does not work.

```
 SELECT
 fullvisitorid,
 max(case when hits.customdimensions.index = 30 then 
hits.customdimensions.value end) customerId,
 visitId,
 DATEDIFF(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime), 
 SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(prevVisitStartTime)) AS daysSinceLastSession,
 FLOOR((visitStartTime - prevVisitStartTime)/60) as minutesSinceLastSession
 FROM (
 SELECT
    fullvisitorid,
    max(case when hits.customdimensions.index = 30 then 
    hits.customdimensions.value end) customerId,
    visitId,
    visitStartTime,
    LAG(visitStartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorid ORDER BY 
    visitStartTime ASC) AS prevVisitStartTime,



   FROM
   TABLE_DATE_RANGE([DATA],
   TIMESTAMP ('2017-04-01'),
   TIMESTAMP ('2017-04-08')))
```

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: What is `hits`?  Is it the table you are using?

Comment: That is the field name for the custom dimension, which exists in the Google Analytics data with the index of '30'.

Answer (score 0):

MAX is an aggregation function - you have to group it somehow, either over the whole table with `GROUP BY` or within the row, e.g. with `WITHIN RECORD` or `WITHIN hits`

To get custom dimension values for each session you need to `MAX( IF(hits.customdimensions.index = 30,hits.customdimensions.value,NULL) ) WITHIN RECORD`

This line is first producing a list of values for each session (`RECORD`) and `customDimension` - the value if index is 30 and NULL else:
`MAX(NULL, NULL, NULL, ..., <value for hits.cd30>, ... , NULL, NULL, ... <another hits.cd30>, ... , NULL)`

Where `NULL` is the lowest possible value. Strings are sorted alphabetically (actually by code table, but they contain characters sorted alphabetically) - since you're aggregating hit-level customDimensions on session level your list might contains multiple non-null values for sessions with more than one hit, because there might be multiple cd30s. `MAX()` returns the one that comes latest in the alphabet: `"aab" < "aac" < "b"`